# Setting up xdebug on local drive or vps?

Tags: php, xdebug, vps

I'm interested in trying xdebug to debug some applications I'm developing in PHP, however I'm not sure whether it would be advantageous to either install it locally on my xampp configuration or on my remove VPS server.

Are there any benefits to doing either? One of my concerns is my remote VPS has a limited amount of memory and I'm worried about any unnecessary overhead/memory consumption, however I'm prepared to make the sacrifice if installing it on my remove VPS will bring me certain benefits.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the newer version does allow you to filter which IP addresses to send debug information to, the fact is that XDebug connects back to your computer to work with the debugger (hence, increasing the ability for someone else to grab information from the live site).

I would suggest that if you can avoid it, don't install the XDebug extension into your VPS... Besides, if you're doing all of your development locally, isn't that the more beneficial place to have the debugger?

Comment: That makes sense. My main aim is to use it for assessing code execution speed. I will do as you advise and install it locally to do any debugging that's required. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should install it on your development machine, if you need it of course. If you don't then there is no need for it.

I can usually get around with `var_dump()`s, but it is sometimes much easier to find a bug using xdebug + NetBeans. YMMV.

You should never use xdebug on a production machine, unless you really can't duplicate the bug elsewhere - and even then you should probably use logging to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup. I use XDEBUG with XAMPP on my dev server, and installed XDEBUG on my VPS thinking I'd use it directly on VPS.

But till date I haven't used it on VPS, and the local installation has sufficed.

The only benifit I can see using XDEBUG on the live instalation is the ability to test on live data. But you can get around it by using a database dump from VPS on your local Machine.

As others have said XAMPP connects back and though you can filter it by IP, it *May* be a security issue.

I would suggest install it on both local and VPS, and see if you actually need it on VPS.